# How to find the minimum value from all the columns in a table?

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm developing an Android app and it requires me to implement an SQLite Database (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html). I have a table with multiple columns, all containing ***NUMBER*** type data. I need to find the minimum value from all the columns combined. For example, if my table looks like this -

```
Column1    Column2    Column3
=======    =======    =======
   1000       2000       1500
   2000       4500       5000
    500       2500        500
```

The minimum value of column1 is 500, column2 is 2000 and column3 is 500. The overall minimum in the table would be 500. To find this value, I'm using the ***UNION*** clause. My query -

```
SELECT MIN (a) FROM (
SELECT MIN (Column1) FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT MIN (Column2) FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT MIN (Column3) FROM MyTable
) AS a
```

The above query is executed in my app using the rawQuery method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#rawQuery%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29)

This query seems to work on Oracle SQL*Plus, but not on SQLite. According to a few tutorials I found on Google, my syntax appears to be correct. But I get an error in my LogCat saying ***"no such column: a"***, and my app shuts down.

I would really appreciate a few pointers as to what part of my query is incorrect. Other methods to achieve the same result are also appreciated.

Thanks,
Rohan

Note: This is my first question on StackOverflow, so if I missed some important information, please let me know :)

Comment: replace `MIN (Column1)` to `MIN (Column1) AS b` then `MIN(a)` to `MIN (b)` ... `a` is an alias for table not colum in that table ...

Comment: can't you just use `order by`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to name your column in at least the first query in the union, otherwise it will not have the name `a` in the outer query;

```
SELECT MIN (a) AS a FROM (
  SELECT MIN (Column1) AS a FROM MyTable
  UNION
  SELECT MIN (Column2)      FROM MyTable
  UNION
  SELECT MIN (Column3)      FROM MyTable
)
```

If your columns are indexed individually or as the first field of a composite index, using MIN in this way will allow use of [MIN/MAX optimisation](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#minmax) (thanks @CL.), although I'd use `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` to avoid a `DISTINCT` step.

As an alternate version you could use `MIN` a single time instead. This should be as efficient as above if your table isn't indexed to use the optimisation above.

```
SELECT MIN(a) AS a FROM (
  SELECT column1 AS a FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT column2      FROM MyTable
  UNION ALL  
  SELECT column3      FROM MyTable
)
```

There's also a briefer way to get the result if you're willing to use a "SQLite-ism" that `MIN` with multiple values will get the smallest value. Since this query contains more than a single `MIN()`, it will not use MIN/MAX optimisation either.

```
SELECT MIN( MIN(column1), MIN(column2), MIN(column3) ) AS a FROM MyTable;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test all of them](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5458d/2).

Comment: Only the first query allows the [MIN optimization](http://www.sqlite.org/optoverview.html#minmax) and thus is the most efficient one.

Comment: @CL. Updated with more detailed info on that, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

use this method to find the minimum value

```
database_instance.rawQuery("SELECT MIN(coloumn1_name) FROM table_name",null);
```

same for coloumn2 and 3

Comment: can someone please tell me why the downvote i really want to know what i have done wrong here

Comment: @Selvin can you explain me why its not right answer because i think its perfectly fine,because if it is not right i want to correct it

Comment: right answer is my comment or Jochim answer ... while your code should work, but is not answering the question ... he dont need multiple minimums for all columns but one minimum from all tables and columns